# Multiple asynchronous file upload asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, asynchronous

I am using Ajax asynchronous file upload control in asp.net. In my application there are 2 such upload controls. When i am uploading one file at a time, both files are getting uploaded. But when i am uploading 2 files simultaneously , only first file is getting uploaded. can you please tell me, What will be the root cause  and Solution for this?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solutions for this. I have added different update panel for each file upload control and set updatemode to conditional. This fixed the problem.